# WiFi repeater with only built in WiFi chip

Tags: pi-3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, and because it has built in WiFi, is there any way to create virtual adapters so it can be connected to a WiFi network and be broadcasting one?

Answer (score 2):

You may check this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161001142107/https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) that can create a virtual AP with `Raspberry Pi 3`. If the virtual AP work but not the Pi, then you may need to create static IP routes to enable the Pi to connect to the network.

Hope this help.

Comment: At a glance on the setup given by the link I cannot find how to create a virtual interface for the access point. So it seems that it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Some years later with modern operating system using **systemd-networkd** there is a setup available that is tested with Raspberry Pi. It uses only the built-in WiFi device and creates a virtual interface **ap0** that is used for the access point. The physical interface **wlan0** is used for the uplink client connection to the (internet) router so it works as WiFi repeater. How to setup this you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).