# Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge

Tags: wifi, ethernet, access-point, systemd-networkd

I need a wireless access point that is bridged with the wired ethernet port and that is connected to another wifi internet router with a client connection as uplink. All devices connected to the RasPi either by wifi or by wired ethernet should have access to the internet and should be able to connect to each other.

How can I achieve this with a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

We are talking about an access point together with a wireless client connection on interface **wlan0** to another wifi network (wlan repeater) or an internet router.

If you want an access point together with an ethernet interface **eth0** for a wired uplink to a switch or an internet router then look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/88214/79866).

Tested on a Raspberry Pi 4B with
[Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop 2020-08-20](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2020-08-24/) updated on 2020-09-01.
[Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop 2020-05-27](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2020-05-28/) updated on 2020-06-11.
[Raspbian Buster Lite 2020-02-13](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2020-02-14/) updated on 2020-03-03.
Updates done with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo reboot`.

Here you will find the [last tested revision for Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/revisions/89804/26).

**IMPORTANT UPDATE** on 2020-09-02:
I have found that the image versions of the **Raspberry Pi OS** come with an unstable firmware for the built-in WiFi device. For further information look at my bug report at [WiFi firmware brcmfmac crashes when using virtual AP interface](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1463). The last stable is [firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/) comming with image **Raspbian Buster Lite 2020-02-13**.

So we have to downgrade the WiFi firmware to this stable version as long as the bug isn't fixed. After flashing the *Raspberry Pi OS* image with update/full-upgrade, follow this to do downgrade:

```
rpi ~$ wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --purge firmware-brcm80211
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg --install firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb
rpi ~$ sudo apt-mark hold firmware-brcm80211
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

---

The Raspberry Pi is able to work as a wireless hotspot and simultaneously connect to another hotspot as a client. But the wifi device on the RasPi has a general limitation. The client connection cannot be bridged because lack of WDS (wireless distribution system) that is needed for bridging on the wireless. For further information look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866). So we can only use routing for the wifi client connection to the internet router. But the wifi hotspot and the wired ethernet port can be bridged so all devices on wifi and the wired port can have the same broadcast domain on its common subnet.

I assume that you already have a connection to the internet. All commands can simply be copied and pasted to the command line of the RasPi. The blocks with EOF you can select from `cat` incl. the last `EOF` and paste it to the RasPis command line. With *Enter* it will be copied to a file without the delimiter EOF.

We will first setup a **wifi repeater** so if anyone only needs this he can stop setup at this point and use it. For those who need a **bridged ethernet port** with the wifi access point can continue with setting it up.

I use *systemd-networkd* for reasons. For the impatient first only the Setup.

---

### ♦ Setup wifi repeater

Example for this setup:

```
                 wifi                         wifi uplink         wan
mobile-phone <~.~.~.~.~> (ap@wlan0)RPi(wlan0) <.~.~.~.~.> router <───> INTERNET
            ╲             ╱               ╲
           (dhcp    192.168.4.1          (dhcp
         from RPi)                    from router)
```

#### Step 1: setup systemd-networkd

Just follow to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). You can use section **"♦ Quick Step"**. Then come back here.

#### Step 2: install hostapd for the access point

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es   # if not already done
rpi ~# apt install hostapd
```

Create this file with your settings for `ssid=`, `country_code=` and `wpa_passphrase=`. As `channel=` select the same channel *wpa_supplicant* with **wlan0** will connect to your internet router.
**ATTENTION! This is a restriction from the hardware. `hostapd` will always set the channel to the same value than from the client connection, no matter what you set here.** If you need different channels then you have to use an additional USB/WiFi dongle.

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf <<EOF
driver=nl80211
ssid=RPiNet
country_code=DE
hw_mode=g
channel=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=verySecretPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Create a service for the accesspoint with hostapd:

```
rpi ~# systemctl edit --force --full accesspoint@.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version)
Wants=wpa_supplicant@%i.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev %i interface add ap@%i type __ap
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -i ap@%i /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw dev ap@%i del

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
```

Enable the service:

```
rpi ~# systemctl enable accesspoint@wlan0.service
rpi ~# rfkill unblock wlan
```

#### Step 3: setup wpa_supplicant for client connection

Create this file with your settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=` and enable it:

```
rpi ~# cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="realyNotMyPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK   # see ref (4)
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
```

Extend wpa_supplicant with:

```
rpi ~# systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements. Save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=accesspoint@%i.service
After=accesspoint@%i.service
```

#### Step 4: setup static interfaces

Create these files:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wl*
[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
# If you need a static ip address, then toggle commenting next four lines (example)
DHCP=yes
#Address=192.168.50.60/24
#Gateway=192.168.50.1
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

For those who want a bridge, do not need the next file and must continue with **Setup bridge**.

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-ap.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=ap@*
[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
IPMasquerade=yes
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

Setup a wifi repeater without bridge is finished. You must
Reboot.

---

### ♦ Setup bridge

**Setup wifi repeater** as described above.

Example for this setup:

```
          (dhcp
        from RPi)        bridge
           ╱    wifi    ┌──────┐
mobile-phone <~.~.~.~.> │(ap@) │           wifi uplink         wan
                        │   br0│RPi(wlan0) <.~.~.~.~.> router <───> INTERNET
      laptop <────────> |(eth0)│╲       ╲
           ╲    wired   └──────┘╱      (dhcp
         (dhcp           192.168.4.1   from router)
       from RPi)
```

#### Step 5: configure hostapd for a bridge

Add a line `bridge=br0` to */etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf* with:

```
rpi ~# echo 'bridge=br0' >> /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

#### Step 6: setup wpa_supplicant for a bridge

Extend wpa_supplicant with:

```
rpi ~# systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

In the editor append lines so it looks like the following. Have attention to the minus sign after equal `=-` on some statements. Save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=accesspoint@%i.service
After=accesspoint@%i.service

[Service]
ExecStartPost=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=%i --timeout=60 --quiet
ExecStartPost=/bin/ip link set ap@%i up
ExecStopPost=-/bin/ip link set ap@%i up
```

Please note that `ExecStopPost=-/bin/ip link set ap@%i up` is not a typo. On stopping wpa_supplicant, interface **ap@wlan0** must be set **up** again.

#### Step 7: setup static interfaces

For a bridge **ap@wlan** is dynamically created. So create these files:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/02-br0.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Bridge=br0
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/16-br0_up.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=br0
[Network]
IPMasquerade=yes
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

Reboot.
That's it.

---

### ♦ Details

#### General

One problem is that we want to use the same device for a wifi client and for an access point. This must be supported by the wifi hardware. We can check this with

```
rpi ~$ sudo iw list | grep -A4 "valid interface combinations:"
        valid interface combinations:
             * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
               total <= 3, #channels <= 2
             * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
               total <= 4, #channels <= 1
```

The important part is  `#{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1,` but you can also see that **this is only possible on one channel**.

I've found that we have to setup this in sequence, otherwise, it won't work. If other applications bind to the wifi port it cannot be set.

1. **create a virtual interface `ap@wlan0` for the access point**
2. **start access point daemon `hostapd` using interface `ap@wlan0`**
3. **start `wpa_supplicant` for wifi client using interface `wlan0`**

This order restricts the whole setup. It isn't possible to start *hostapd* when *wpa_supplicant* is running. You must first stop *wpa_supplicant* and then start *hostapd* and *wpa_supplicant* in this order. This is due to the WiFi driver `brcmfmac`.

Another quirk is that *wpa_supplicant* disables the interface **ap@wlan0** when it is managed, no matter if it starts or stops. So even after a start from *wpa_supplicant*, we have to enable **ap@wlan0** again.

Here are mainly four components involved: virtual interface **ap@wlan0**, *hostapd*, *wpa_supplicant*, and setup the bridge.

#### hostapd (Step 2)

This is the normal setup you will find all over the web. Please set the channel to the same value then **wlan0** is connected to the wifi from your router. It is the restriction from the hardware and may avoid confusion with channel settings. *hostapd* will always set the channel to the same value than from the client connection, no matter what you set here.

Please use a passphrase that is long enough, I would say at least with 8 characters. It was told that 4 characters are too small and hostapd will refuse to accept connections. You will not find the access point **RPiNet** on your mobile phone (thanks to [@Leo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/91016/leo)).

We do not need to unmask the hostapd.service as described at `/usr/share/doc/hostapd/README.Debian` because we create our own `accesspoint@.service` for hostapd.

In this service the interface **ap@wlan0** is created before starting *hostapd*. This is respected to the starting order. Because **ap@wlan0** is bound to **wlan0** it gets the same mac address. You may consider to give it a unique mac address but that's not a good idea. On the network is only seen the mac address from **wlan0**. If you give **ap@wlan0** its own mac address then it is not seen on the network for arp requests and the IP address for connections to **ap@wlan0** is not found and gets stuck. You have to set **ap@wlan0** to promiscuous mode to get it to work then.

After stopped *hostapd* then **ap@wlan0** is also deleted so it can be created again on the next start of *hostapd*.

#### wpa_supplicant (Step 3)

Setting up *wpa_supplicant* for **wlan0** we do as usual. You may consider to disable p2p with `p2p_disabled=1` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` to avoid to get the unneeded confusing P2P-device seen with `iw dev`. Don't do that in this configuration with a virtual AP interface (e.g. ap@wlan0). It confuses wpa_supplicant and it will immediately disconnect from the uplink router when it has just connected to it. It endless connect and disconnect.

Its extended unit is to strictly bind *wpa_supplicant* to *hostapd* so it will start and stop with it in the right order. We do it because running *wpa_supplicant* without *hostapd* is very complicated and may result in a total crash of the *brcmfmac* wifi driver, I have seen that on my tests.

#### Setup static interfaces (Step 4)

Here we define interface **wlan0** and the virtual interface **ap@wlan0** we need for a wifi repeater. For **wlan0** we get an IP address by DHCP from the internet router. Optional you can set a static IP address, but then you also have to define all other settings like gateway and DNS server because you don't get them anymore from the DHCP server.

Interface **ap@wlan0** needs a static IP address because it is the access point and the source of the DHCP server for the wifi network. There is no need that clients, connected to the internet router, must also connect to clients on the access point. So we can use NAT  (IPMasquerade=yes) that simplifies setup a lot. Then we don't have to configure static routes and it is not needed to configure **wlan0** with static values (IP address, gateway, DNS server, etc.).

#### hostapd for bridge (Step 5)

We have setup *hostapd* in Step 2. Now we only need to append `bridge=br0` to its configuration so that it will dynamically manage to add **ap@wlan0** to the bridge.

#### wpa_supplicant for bridge (Step 6)

When wpa_supplicant is started it also brings up interface **wlan0**. Every time it is managed, no matter if it started or stopped, it will stop **ap@wlan0** because it is not a real interface and depends directly on **wlan0**.

The ap interface can only start when **wlan0** "Gained carrier" and the link becomes ready [**(3)**](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/936). This will happen some or more seconds after *wpa_supplicant* has started. There is a helper program *systemd-networkd-wait-online* that can do this synchronous. We use it with a timeout of 60 seconds. If your network connection takes longer than 60 seconds to get up,  then you should increase the timeout accordingly. With `journalctl -b -e` you can check if `Starting Bring up wifi interface ap@wlan0...` and `Started Bring up wifi interface ap@wlan0.` covers `wlan0: Gained carrier`. This is very important because otherwise, the bridge will not work correctly with undefined behavior. You can check the helpers options with `/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --help`.

After stopped wpa_supplicant (bring **wlan0** down) **ap@wlan0** must be brought up again so it can continue running for the access point.

#### define static interfaces for bridge (Step 7)

These files define the bridge. **ap@wlan0** will dynamically be added by *hostapd*. **eth0** and **ap@wlan0** are slaves of the bridge and don't need an IP address. The bridge **br0** itself also does not need an IP address but here it has a static IP address because we need it for the DHCP server bound to **br0** so the DHCP server is available on the subnet of the bridge ( interfaces eth0, ap@wlan0).

#### Conclusion

**Update** 2020-07-22:
[Bassline Soup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/120864/bassline-soup) has made some [interesting tests](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113521/79866) that may help to troubleshoot the setup.

---

You are now able to start, stop and restart *hostapd* and *wpa_supplicant*.

You should see the access point, here *RPiNet*, in your mobile phone and should get an IP address to connect to the access point. You should also get an IP address from the same subnet if you connect a laptop with a cable to the ethernet port and you can ping the mobile phone.

With this setup you have the following dependencies with starting and stopping:

```
 hostapd   │ wpa_supplicant      wpa_supplicant │  hostapd
───────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────
 starting  │    starts              starting    │  starts
 stopping  │    stops               stopping    │   ----
restarting │   restarts            restarting   │  starts
```

This is because of the strict order of starting (see section *General*). You cannot run *wpa_supplicant* without *hostapd* but you can run *hostapd* without *wpa_supplicant* by starting *hostapd* and then stop *wpa_supplicant*.

If communication stops for some reason (e.g. delay to small or something else) it is mostly enough to kick **ap@wlan0** with `/bin/ip link set ap@wlan0 up`.

**references:**
[1] [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866)
[2] man systemd.unit
[3] [systemd-networkd wireless bridging - need to wait for carrier](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/936)
[4] [Setup WiFi on Pi 3 B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/97939/79866)

Comment: This looks like a good tutorial (I have not tried it, having no desire for the functionality). I have a couple of concerns - you seem to be logged as root; the Raspbian does not have root a/c and there is no explanation. Why "# cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF" when you could just list the files (and use sudo to copy)?

Comment: @Milliways There are a couple of commands they all must be prefixed with `sudo`. To simplify it I like to work in a shell with user environment but with root rights. You can simply invoke this with `sudo -Es`. You will find it in the steps and you will find also an `exit` (if not rebooting).

Comment: @Milliways I very often need the setup sequences for testing and optimizing. If I only list the files I have to invoke an editor, copy and paste it into it, save and quit the editor. With this `cat >filename <<EOF` thing I only select the block with my mouse and paste it with the middle button of my mouse to the prompt of my RasPi console - very quick and efficient.

Comment: I tried it and works like a dream (No Bridge). I did it on a Rasp Zero W. Thanks!

Comment: @Milliways: "The Raspbian does not have root a/c" It sure does: `$ sudo su; # _`

Comment: @RobinDinse Do you mean settings "*wpa_supplicant for bridge (Step 6)*"? No, it **must** be setting ap `up` again as you can read in section **Details - wpa_supplicant for bridge (Step 6)**. I will give a hint in the setup section.

Comment: @RobinDinse Yes it can. If you follow the instructions with care then it shouldn't be created at all. At the end of section **Setup wifi repeater** you will find the sentence "*For those who want a bridge, do not need the next file and must continue with Setup bridge.*" before to create the file for **ap0**. On **Setup bridge - Step 8: setup static interfaces** you find "*For a bridge **ap0** is dynamically created.*". I don't expect that everyone read all details. As you suggested I will delete the comments in some hours.

Comment: This was tricky, but I solved it eventually. I ditched hostapd for another wpa_supplicant instance as you described in [your RPi.SE answer on setting up an access point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234), but this still did not work. The problem turned out to be the automatic naming scheme which switched around `wlan0` and `wlan1` under some circumstances, so I had to enforce static naming in `/etc/udev/rules.d/72-static-name.rules`. (My Wi-Fi dongle does not support AP mode.)

Comment: Thanks soooo much for that detailed answer @Ingo! 
Got my RPi as a wifi and eth "bridge" basically working. Had to execute the steps from the "extended troubleshooting" section and some further steps. As it turns out on "Raspbian 10 (buster)" with latest updates(?) you can't simply install and start dnsmasq, as on port 53 there's already a DNS-Service running.
I had to edit `sudo vi /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and set `DNSStubListener=no` to make any progress (can't reconstruct where i found that solution actually :().

Comment: "Basically working" because my phone and computer show terrible package loss and the RPi kind of grinds to a halt (network wise; no cpu utilization though) when the network is in use for a certain time. Rebooting solves this temporarily. 
This might be a whole other issue with WIFI bands crossover or a defective hardware unit on my side though.

Comment: @icyerasor If you install *dnsmasq* it may conflict with the the built-in DHCP server from *systemd-networkd*. You should disable the DHCP server part in *dnsmasq* or just omit all **DHCPServer** options in the *.network files. I would let *systemd-networkd* do the job because it knows best what ip addresses its interfaces have.

Comment: @Ingo Hmmn when using it i could not resolve ip addresses at all on my clients iirc. So I followed your steps described in the "Troubleshooting" section.
But I might give it another try by switching back sometime.

Comment: @icyerasor Ah ok, I see now... Don't had a look at the section for a long time. You are right.

Comment: Hehe no problem. Anyway - thank you very much for sharing that knowledge. Linux hardware configs are sometimes still a closed book to me 

Comment: @Ingo if I intend to use wifi for configuring wifi. That is, have a REST API on ap0 which accepts the wifi credentials that wlan0 should connect to, then will I be able to change the wpa_supplicant.conf entries and connect RPi to that wifi without reboot? I am running into problems with the other setup of dual mode wifi after I change the ssid and password in wpa_supplicant.conf on the fly and then do ifdown and ifup on the wlan0 interface. The ap0 no longer accepts connections and even the wlan0 keeps connecting disconneting every 2 seconds... so basically everthing stops working.

Comment: @thewebjackal You explain details for a solution you have in your mind. I can't see if it's possible. Better you tell what you want to achieve in general because I believe there are better/simpler or possible solutions, maybe something with wifi direct in addition to the AP for configuration?

Comment: Yes @Ingo. I am trying a dual mode wifi on RPi ZW. The purpose of the ap0 will be to get the ssid and pass (supplied from a mobile app) that the wlan0 interface must connect to. No repeater here. I have tried by following these steps here: https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/ and the docker container here: https://imti.co/iot-wifi/. When I supply ssid and password and force a connection using ifdown wlan0 followed by ifup wlan0, problem starts. The wlan0 keeps disconnecting and ap0 (visible in scans) doesn't accept connections.

Comment: Also @Ingo. I have not yet tried implementing your solution. I will try and get back to you asap. I have been very inconsiderate by not showing thanking you for sharing such in detail guide. Apologies for that. and ofcourse thank you!

Comment: Hello @Ingo. I have done the above mentioned setup without the bridge on Stretch. So, for now I am manually changing the entry in wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf file. For that to take effect, I am able to get desired results by either running wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure or systemctl restart wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service. The issue with ap0 going down and wlan0 disconnecting continuously does not seem to happen now. I will have to do some more testing. However, which of the above mentioned commands will you suggest (wpa_cli or systemctl) for making things work in a long run?

Comment: @thewebjackal To manage wpa_suppliant as service, e.g. start, stop, restart, enable, disable etc, I would use systemd. This way systemd always nows the state of the service. To manage details of wpa_supplicant, e.g. dynamically add a network, force to connect to a specific hotspot etc., I would use wpa_cli. In general: if possible, use systemctl.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the advice. I will stick to systemctl.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! Did anyone temper with IPv4ProxyARP to get wlan0 and ap0 on the same subnet?

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

Comment: @n1nj4 I do not understand your link to the man page of systemd.network. If you want to use proxy arp you can look at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866).

Comment: @Ingo, the above link describes `IPv4ProxyARP` in `systemd.network`, natively. Unfortunately that feates is poorly documented.

Comment: @n1nj4 Ah.. sorry, haven't realized that, Will have a look at it.

Comment: I did it up to "Setup a wifi repeater without bridge is finished. You must Reboot." but when I reboot the Pi hangs during bootup at the "Welcome to Raspberry Pi Desktop" screen.  On the lower left I can see it is stuck at systemd-hostnamed.service.  Now I can't do anything to my Pi.  Is there some troubleshooting I can do without logging in (which I cannot do because ssh is not on under preferences)

Comment: @Chiwda Recently I have updated the setup with systemd name resolution. Maybe there is an issue? I will check it, just a moment please...

Comment: @Ingo The step of "apt install libnss-resolve" fails because there are problems with DNS resolution.  Could this be the cause of my failed installation?

Comment: @Chiwda I have seen some problems with DNSSEC, so I disabled it everywhere. Have a look at the [revision comparison](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/89804/revisions) what has changed.

Comment: I followed this on my Zero W and it sort of works. I've held back the firmware as described. But there's a lot of latency (avg 500 ms max 1500 ms) on both wlan0 and ap0, and sometimes some ploss. I also notice in `top` that significant CPU (15%) is being used by `kworker/u2:1-brcmf_wq/mmc1:0001:01` and all I'm doing is viewing `top` SSH. This appears to be the driver? Any ideas?

Comment: @tyrel The driver is a mess, but I haven't tested the latest versions. And I don't test them against performance, only against stability. You may try the latest version. You may also consider to use an [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866).

Comment: Just been working with pi-gen /10/4/2021 and noticed that the brcm80211 driver in the image is the one which @Ingo recommends

Comment: Hii, can you explain how did you made the diagram? Is there any tool, or did you draw it by your hand in spare-time? It really helps in explaining things easily and more widely in less words (visually).

Comment: I'm not able to set it up, `RTNETLINK answers: Name not unique on network` comes up when turning both AP and Station mode (non-bridged). Closest I could find is https://stackoverflow.com/q/51040111/11377112 I think, but it doesn't really help much as it says to change mac address of one of them, but I don't know how.

Comment: Ohk, so I was able to change using https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21841/make-some-virtual-mac-address (addr option), but wpa_supplicant service fails to start with `nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured. ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it. Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan1' manually if it is not used anymore.`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Some years later ;-) I made the diagrams by hand, character by character. Me helped it a lot to have other diagrams in other Q&A so I can copy and paste components and just connect them with some dashes.

Answer (score 11):

This is in addition to the [Ingo’s outstanding description](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/126729). Here we would like to use the default networking system of Raspbian (assuming to have previously configured it) rather than replacing it with [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd).

The standard networking mode to configure TCP/IP in Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS is mentioned in the [related documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/). At the time of writing, [dhcpcd is used](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/tcpip/README.md) (*dhcpcd5* package). This mode replaced the former [Debian Networking](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) (*ifupdown* package), where the configuration was done in [/etc/network/interfaces](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html). The [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/) also describes [how to setup a Wi-Fi client/Wi-Fi station](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) via [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wpa_supplicant) by configuring
[/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) to connect the Raspberry Pi to an existing wireless LAN on its default *wlan0* interface; alternatively, it describes how to set up a [routed wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) on the same *wlan0* interface (instead of the Wi-Fi station).
We will use [this last document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) as a reference, changing it in just a few points to configure the same wireless board to enable a *wlan0* interface (Wi-Fi Client/Station, connected to another wifi network or internet router) as well as a Wi-Fi Access Point named *uap0* (e.g., to define a wlan repeater):

- we create a copy of the *hostapd* service configuration, adding *ExecStartPre* and *ExecStopPost* settings to add/remove the "type AP" virtual interface via *iw*; we prefer using this rather than adding a rule in [/etc/udev/rules.d](https://wiki.debian.org/udev);
- we use *dhcpcd* to set a static IP address to the created interface, also modifying the *wlan0* configuration, to act as a DHCP client (without static addressing)

As DNS forwarder and DHCP Server, we will keep [dnsmasq](https://wiki.debian.org/dnsmasq), used in the previously mentioned Raspberry configuration. We will also keep [DNS Multicast](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) (*libnss-mdns*) and Zeroconf/Apple Bonjour (*avahi-daemon*). We will not use *systemd-resolved*.

Noticeably, we suppose that the older [ifupdown](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/index.html) mode is not used, meaning that [/etc/network/interfaces](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html) is left to its default configuration, with no stanzas defined, apart from `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d`, with any other note or statement commented out through an initial `#`, and that */etc/network/interfaces.d* directory is left empty. We also assume that `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd` returns that the service is active.

Example for this setup:

```
(dhcp 192.168.1.3 from router)  +----------------------+   (192.168.1.1
                             \  |                      |  / +DHCP server)
                 wifi        (eth0)      wifi uplink   | /
mobile-phone <~.~.~.~.~> (ap0)RPi(wlan0) <.~.~.~.~.> router <───> INTERNET
            ╲             ╱          ╲                        wan
(dhcp 192.168.50.50 (192.168.50.1   (dhcp 192.168.1.2
          from RPi) +DHCP server)    from router)
```

Install *dnsmasq* and *hostapd* (like in Raspberry’s documentation):

```sh
sudo -Es
apt install -y dnsmasq hostapd
```

Configure *hostapd* for the Access Point:

```sh
test -f /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf || cat > /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf <<\EOF
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
driver=nl80211
country_code=IT # Use your country code
ssid=YourSessionIdentifier
hw_mode=g
channel=7
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=verySecretPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
EOF

chmod 600 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
# edit /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf and verify it
```

Test creation and deletion of *uap0* virtual device on *wlan0*:

```sh
/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add uap0 type __ap
/sbin/iw dev uap0 del
```

No error should be produced.
If the first command fails with *Device or resource busy (-16)*, it means that the device driver does not allow creating additional "Type AP" interfaces, which are busy for other services (e.g., an *AP* or a *P2P-GO* group is already active and has to be deleted to allow this new service to be activated).

Check this command:

```sh
iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A 8
```

It should return one line including *AP*. If only *STA* and *managed* are returned, the device driver of the board (or the hw itself) does not allow creating an AP interface.
Output of the Raspberry Pi 4:

```
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
```

Use this command to check the allowed combination options:

```sh
iw list | grep "valid interface combinations" -A 8
```

Every line contains alternative combinations. With the Broadcom BCM2711 SoC included in a Raspberry Pi 4 B, I get the following:

```
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 2
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
                   total <= 4, #channels <= 1
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
        Supported extended features:
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in station mode
```

It means that not more than one AP or P2P-GO interface can be configured at the same time.

If the test to create and delete the *uap0* virtual device succeeds, you can go on, starting the *uap0* AP virtual interface on *wlan0*:

```
SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee systemctl edit --force --full uap@.service <<\EOF
[Unit]
Description=IEEE 802.11 %p%i AP on wlan%i with hostapd
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/hostapd.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2
Environment=DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/hostapd
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan%i interface add %p%i type __ap
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -i %p%i -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF}
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw dev %p0 del

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

systemctl stop hostapd # if the default hostapd service was active before
systemctl disable hostapd # if the default hostapd service was enabled before
systemctl enable uap@0.service
rfkill unblock wlan
```

You might possibly want to manually edit this in the future, with:

```sh
sudo -Es
#export SYSTEMD_EDITOR=vi # uncomment this if you like "vi", otherwise "edit" will be used
export SYSTEMD_EDITOR=vi systemctl edit --full uap@.service
exit
```

Some configurations (especially related to the old *ifupdown* mode) consider adding a static rule in */etc/udev/rules.d* to bring up the *uap0* AP interface, like `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="ieee80211", KERNEL=="phy0", RUN+="/sbin/iw phy %k interface add uap0 type __ap"`; as we are parametrizing this with the `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStopPost` statements of the `uap@` service definition, it is important that your configuration does not include such rule in */etc/udev/rules.d*.

Now we setup *wpa_supplicant* for client connections.

We need to update [dhcpcd](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.8.en.html) (the default a DHCP client) by editing [/etc/dhcpcd.conf](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5.en.html), adding the following to the end (these settings replace the configuration suggested in Raspberry’s site, which defined a static address to *wlan0* instead of a DHCP Client; ref. "Define the wireless interface IP configuration"):

```
interface wlan0 # these two lines are not strictly needed, as wlan0 uses the default configuration
    dhcp

interface uap0 # this defines static addressing to uap0 and disables wpa_supplicant for this interface
    static ip_address=192.168.50.1/24
    ipv4only
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Comparing with the description in Raspberry’s site, notice that, other than removing the static address, we will not use `nohook wpa_supplicant` under *interface wlan0*, so that *wpa_supplicant* is activated by a default *dhcpcd* hook.

To verify this hook, check files included in the [*/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks* directory](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.en.html): one of this is *10-wpa_supplicant*, which is the responsible for activating *wpa_supplicant* on the new interface. It is automatically run when the new interface is discovered by [dhcpcd](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.8.en.html).

The file used by *wpa_supplicant* (Wi-Fi Station agent) is the default one:  */etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf*. We assume that it is already configured and working; otherwise you can use a template to configure it:

```sh
test -f /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf || cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf <<\EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IT

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="realyNotMyPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF
# edit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and verify it

chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service # not used, as the agent is hooked by dhcpcd
```

We can then follow Raspberry’s documentation to enable routing and IP masquerading:

```sh
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y netfilter-persistent iptables-persistent
```

Create a file using the following command, with the contents below:

```sh
test -f /etc/sysctl.d/routed-ap.conf || cat >/etc/sysctl.d/routed-ap.conf <<\EOF
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md
# Enable IPv4 routing
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
EOF
# edit /etc/sysctl.d/routed-ap.conf and verify it
```

Updating the firewall rules:

```sh
# Add firewall rules
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o uap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i uap0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

*dnsmasq* configuration follows Raspberry’s example:

```sh
cat >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf <<\EOF

# disables dnsmasq reading any other files like /etc/resolv.conf for nameservers
no-resolv

interface=uap0
no-dhcp-interface=lo,wlan0
domain-needed
bogus-priv
server=8.8.8.8
dhcp-range=192.168.50.50,192.168.50.199,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.50.1
EOF

# edit /etc/dnsmasq.conf and verify it
```

The configuration is finished. You must reboot before testing.

```sh
reboot
```

The *systemctl* command on *uap@0.service* allows disabling, enabling and monitoring the AP function; for instance, to stop AP, to remove the virtual interface and to free up device driver resources, you can issue:

```sh
sudo systemctl stop uap@0
```

To start again the service:

```sh
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd && sudo systemctl start uap@0 && sudo systemctl start dhcpcd
```

Notice that in both cases *wlan0* link goes down for some seconds and then goes up again; an active TCP connection on *wlan0* is not lost anyway.

Temporarily stopping *dhcpcd* before starting up *uap0* is needed to also stop *wpa_supplicant* (hooked by *dhcpcd*); this is in order to avoid the Broadcom driver issue "failed to enable fw supplicant" (for some weird reason the device driver attempts to reload an already loaded firmware supplicant for this interface).

If *wlan1* is configured in place of the default *wlan0* Wi-Fi function of the Raspberry Pi (e.g., a USB wireless dongle supporting access point mode), replace *wlan0* with *wlan1*, *uap@0* with *uap@1*, *uap0* with *uap1*  every time "*wlan0*", "*uap@0*" and "*uap0*" are mentioned.

To use a different root name than *uap* for the AP interface (e.g., referring to *uap0*), change it with the new name every time it is mentioned.

[Raspberry’s documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/) describes how to [set up a Raspberry Pi as a bridged wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md). The Ethernet interface is used to connect the Raspberry to the upstream router (e.g., provided with Internet access and featuring a DHCP server). In such configuration, the Raspberry Pi itself can be accessed by its *br0* wireless interface, but not by its *Ethernet* interface, which participates to the bridging function and is not assigned an IP address; also, to avoid resetting active sessions, the Ethernet interface must not be disconnected from the upstream router. [As described by Ingo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81486/raspberry-pi-wifi-to-ethernet-bridge-for-a-server/81518#81518), it is not possible to bridge the Wi-Fi client connections to the upstream router.

### Testing wpa_supplicant permissions

*wpa_supplicant* is interfaced to *wpa_cli* through UNIX sockets and when logging into the system with *pi* user, you should be able to successfully control *wpa_supplicant* and related configuration.

The following steps allow verifying *wpa_supplicant* permissions.

Check who starts *wpa_supplicant* and that you do not have more services activating this daemon. Assuming that the tested interface is *wlan0*, if you rely on *dhcpcd* you should be able to verify that *wpa_supplicant* does not start after temporarily adding `denyinterfaces wlan0` as the first line of */etc/dhcpcd.conf* (`sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd`).

After restoring */etc/dhcpcd.conf* and restarting the service, you shoud get something like the following with `ps -ef | grep wpa_supplicant`:

```
root       613     1  0 Feb20 ?        01:50:03 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

Notice the *root* user, its dependency to the parent process id *1* and the command line arguments (`-B` means daemon, `-c` with the appropriate configuration file, `-i` with the related interface, `-D` with standard drivers).

Specifically, you need to verify the presence of `-i` command-line option if *wpa_supplicant.conf* declares *GROUP=netdev*.

Check also `journalctl -t dhcpcd-run-hooks`; you should get `dhcpcd-run-hooks[7548]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant`.

If you do `ls -l /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` you should get the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1155 Feb 27 14:26 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Notice the permissions, the owner and the group.

If you edit */etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf*, yous should verify

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
```

Notice */var/run/wpa_supplicant* directory and *netdev* group.

If you do `ls -ld /var/run/wpa_supplicant`, tou should get the following:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 root netdev 100 Feb 20 11:01 /var/run/wpa_supplicant
```

Notice the permissions, the owner which should be *root* and the group which should be *netdev*, thanks to *GROUP=netdev* in *wpa_supplicant.conf*.

If you do `ls -l /var/run/wpa_supplicant`, you should get something like

```
total 0
srwxrwx--- 1 root netdev 0 Feb 20 11:00 p2p-dev-wlan0
srwxrwx--- 1 root netdev 0 Feb 20 11:00 wlan0
```

Notice the presence of the `wlan0` Unix socket (`srwxrwx---`), as well as the P2P Device (*p2p-dev-wlan0*).

Notice the owner, that shall be *root*, and the group, which is again *netdev*.

If you do `iw dev` with *wpa_supplicant* active, one of the returned item should be:

```
        Unnamed/non-netdev interface
                wdev 0x2
                addr ee:11:6c:59:a3:d4
                type P2P-device
                txpower 31.00 dBm
```

which refers to the P2P device (`type P2P-device`).

Now edit */etc/passwd*, check the presence of *root* users and *pi* users:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
...
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
...
```

Edit */etc/group* anch check the *netdev* group:

```
netdev:x:109:pi
```

User *pi* should be associated to a number of groups, including *netdev*.

Now verify that you are logged into the system with *pi user, do `id`:

```
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),105(input),109(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)
```

One of the group shall be `netdev`.

Verify that you can successfully run *wpa_cli*, without a need of *sudo*:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 ping
wpa_cli -i p2p-dev-wlan0 ping
```

You should get *PONG* twice.

Run `wpa_cli -i p2p-dev-wlan0 reconfigure`; you shoud get *OK*.

Comment: Phew. This was a bit over my head but a lifesaver. Thank you! I had to add the down and restart systemctl commands to rc.local to get wlan0 working. Any idea why? I'd previously done things on Buster Lite with https://github.com/lukicdarkoo/rpi-wifi and it appeared to have the same general problem. pulling the plug would get things to boot in the right order but no soft command seems to init properly.

Comment: The rc.local statement you mention to get wlan0 working should not be needed. I recommend starting with a fresh install, then updating the OS to the latest version, then applying the network configuration according to the Raspberry documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md. After checking that it works, you can revise the configuration basing on the notes in this topic.

Comment: Also one thing if i now change my `wpa_supplicant.conf` i have to call `systemctl restart dhcpcd.service` instead of `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`. Is there a better solution!?

Comment: `systemctl restart dhcpcd.service` is a way to kill *wpa_supplicant* and restart it, when *wpa_supplicant* is run as a hook of *dhcpcd*. `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure` asks the currently running *wpa_supplicant* to read again the configuration file. Both should be viable alternatives.

Comment: @ircama thanks for your answer. To get `wpa_cli i wlan0 ... reconfigure` to work as expected i first need to kill the running (started from dhcpcd) `wpa_supplicant` daemon and restart it. After changing `wpa_supplicant.conf` and calling `wpa_cli -i wlan0 ... reconfigure` the changes are applied as expected. Also when i reboot `wlan0` is not connecting. I'm not sure what the problem is so i ended up restarting wpa_supplicant after every reboot that worked :/ ... And yes i used `-p /var/run/wpa_ssuplicant` and `sudo -g netdev` as specified in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: @delijati I am not aware of that issue. Consider anyway that a usual practice would be to update the *wpa_supplicant* configuration via *wpa_cli* (e.g., through a number of `set` commands, then optionally `save_config`) or better via dbus when *wpa_supplicant* is run with the `-u` option (like the NetworkMonitor does: in fact when using the NetworkMonitor, the *wpa_supplicant* configuration file might not even be necessary, as the whole configuration is done via dbus).

Comment: The hangs of AP/Client were unbearable. I think AP+Client via hostap and `/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap@wlan0 type __ap` is simply not working. I hope someone can prove me wrong. I ended up using a cheap 2€ wifi dongle systemd-networkd + 2x wpa_supplicant -> wlan0 (client) and wlan1 (AP). That makes also `wpa_cli ... reconfigure` work like a charm.

Comment: @delijati I added a section named "Testing wpa_supplicant permissions" to the documentation. I would be happy to further update it if I could understand what your problem is. Given that I have a system in line with the described configuration and everything works for me, I can imagine that you might have some permissions problems.

I guess that you have a service that starts *wpa_supplicant* before *dhcpcd* is run. When you restart *dhcpcd*, it kills the process and restarts it with different permissions or configuration.

Comment: I don't think it is the permissions. I tried also tried `nohook` for AP and Client in `dhcpcd.conf` aka starting the normal `wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service`. Everything works and also after a reboot everything is setup right. But the connection to both AP and Client are flaky (slow pings; connection lost) maybe it is my router? (fritz-box 7490). `hw_mode=g channel=6` is set in `hostapd.conf`. btw. should we rather go to a forum or chat or so!?

Comment: At the risk of being shot down because of asking for product suggestions, are there any known USB wifi adapters that support the dual hotspot and client mode that are compatible with built-in drivers on Raspbian/Debian? I tested the Wi-Pi, the Edimax EW-7811Un and a TP-Link TL-WN725N but none seem to have 'managed' and 'AP' interface combinations.

Comment: I have followed this answer and with a little digging I also found that for rpi 3b+, you need to pin to an old driver for it to work. You can check it out in my blog where I have all the details: https://tsopokis.com/posts/raspbery-pi-ap/ .
Now I have a problem when I try to do the same with rpi zero 2w (without pinning). Everything seems to work but packets do not seem to go beyond rpi. 
From the rpi I can ping the internet, from a connected client I can ping the rpi but nothing else. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @ircama after a lot of testing when I ping from the client the packages go through the rpi to the internet, but I never get the replies. It looks as if the replies show up in uap0 but now in wlan0. What kind of magic is that?

Answer (score 8):

This answer is not thought for setup. For setup look at the other answer to this question starting with **Setup wifi repeater**. This is mainly for troubleshooting and to show how it works with detailed commands step by step and checkpoints but without background information. I suppose you **have a monitor, keyboard and mouse attached** to your Raspberry Pi and **have a DHCP server running** on your local wireless network. Ip addresses and other settings in this check up are examples. You have to use yours. You can always look at `journalctl -b -e` for logged information.

`Download ZIP` image [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-11-13](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) to your linux pc.

**Checkpoint 1:** Compare the checksum with that on the download site.

```
pc ~$ sha256sum 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip
```

47ef1b2501d0e5002675a50b6868074e693f78829822eef64f3878487953234d  2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip

**Next step:** Burn the image to an attached SD Card. I assume it is attached to `/dev/sdb`. Look with `lsblk` to what device file your SD Card is attached.

```
pc ~$ unzip -p 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M conv=fsync
```

**Checkpoint 2:** check partitions on the SD Card:

```
pc ~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb print
sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Model: Mass Storage Device (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3965MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  50,2MB  46,0MB  primary  fat32        lba
 2      50,3MB  1866MB  1816MB  primary  ext4
```

**Next step:** Mount the boot partition and create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
pc ~$ mkdir boot/
pc ~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 boot/
pc ~$ sudo editor boot/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Insert this into the empty editor with your settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=`, save it and quit the editor:

```
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="your wifi network"
    psk="YourSecretPassword"
}

pc ~$ sudo umount boot/
```

Put the SD Card into your RasPi and boot.

**Checkpoint 3:** After login, check wifi connection and internet access. The **wlan0** interface must have an ip address:

```
rpi ~$ ip -4 addr show dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.10.112/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

rpi ~$ ping -I wlan0 -c3 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.210.14) from 192.168.10.112 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.210.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=213 ms
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.210.14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.210.14): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=12.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.215/79.965/213.461/94.399 ms
```

Until now we have only done default setup. If you have some trouble then there is a general problem with your network. Check [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/79866) and fix it.

**Next step:** Full upgrade and reboot:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

After reboot and login, switch over to *systemd-networkd*:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# systemctl mask networking.service
rpi ~# systemctl mask dhcpcd.service
rpi ~# sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
rpi ~# sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf

rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Create these files for interfaces **wlan0** and **ap0** with your settings:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
IPForward=yes
DHCP=yes
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-ap0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=ap0
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 84.200.70.40
EOF
```

Rename */etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf* so it matches the interface setting and reboot:

```
rpi ~# mv /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~# systemctl reboot
```

**Checkpoint 4:** After reboot and login check wifi connection with *systemd-networkd*:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
● wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-29 11:07:53 GMT; 24s ago
 Main PID: 415 (wpa_supplicant)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-wpa_supplicant.slice/wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
           └─415 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0

Jan 29 11:07:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Jan 29 11:07:53 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Jan 29 11:07:53 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
Jan 29 11:07:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 34:31:c4:c7:f2:74 (SSID='wlan@hoeft-online.de' freq
Jan 29 11:07:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: wlan0: Associated with 34:31:c4:c7:f2:74
Jan 29 11:07:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 34:31:c4:c7:f2:74 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jan 29 11:07:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 34:31:c4:c7:f2:74 completed [id=0 id_st
Jan 29 11:07:56 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[415]: p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE

rpi ~$ ip -4 addr show dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.10.112/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

rpi ~$ ping -I wlan0 -c3 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.21.238) from 192.168.10.112 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s13-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.21.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from fra16s13-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.21.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=13.4 ms
64 bytes from fra16s13-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.21.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=13.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.203/13.602/14.142/0.418 ms
```

**Checkpoint 5:** IMPORTANT! At this point it must be able to set and delete the virtual interface **ap0** without error messages:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev ap0 info
Interface ap0
        ifindex 5
        wdev 0x5
        addr b8:27:eb:06:e8:8b
        type AP
        wiphy 0
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm

rpi ~$ sudo iw dev ap0 del
rpi ~$
```

**Next step:** Install *hostapd* and helper

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# apt install hostapd rng-tools
rpi ~# systemctl stop hostapd.service
rpi ~# systemctl disable hostapd.service
```

Create this file with your settings for `ssid=` and `wpa_passphrase=`:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf <<EOF
interface=ap0
driver=nl80211
ssid=RPiNet
hw_mode=g
channel=1
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=verySecretPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Set DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf" in /etc/default/hostapd with:

```
rpi ~# sed -i 's/^#DAEMON_CONF=.*$/DAEMON_CONF="\/etc\/hostapd\/hostapd.conf"/' /etc/default/hostapd
```

In */etc/init.d/hostapd* in section *INIT INFO* you have to comment the line `# Should-Start: $network` to `## Should-Start: $network`:

```
rpi ~# sed -i 's/^\(# Should-Start:\s*$network\)$/#\1/' /etc/init.d/hostapd
```

Edit *hostapd.service* with `systemctl edit hostapd.service` and in the empty editor insert this, save and quit:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw dev ap0 del
```

Reboot.

After reboot and login, check client connection together with access point. It is very important that `/sbin/wpa_supplicant` starts **after** `/sbin/hostapd`. Otherwise the wifi driver crashes and you must reboot.

**Checkpoint 6:** interface **wlan0** must have `state DOWN` and **ap0** has `state UP`.

```
rpi ~$ ip link show dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:06:e8:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start hostapd.service
rpi ~$ ip -4 addr show dev ap0
4: ap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.4.1/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global ap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Checkpoint 7:** Check wifi on your mobile phone. You should find `RPiNet` and you can connect to it. Your mobile phone cannot get into the internet because routing isn't configured yet.

**Next step:** Start `wpa_supplicant` after `hostapd`:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

**Checkpoint 8:** Interfaces **wlan0** and **ap0** must have `state UP` and you can ping google.com from the RasPi:

```
rpi ~$ ip -4 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.10.112/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 25393sec preferred_lft 25393sec
4: ap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.4.1/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global ap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

rpi ~$ ping -c3 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.21.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s13-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.21.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from fra16s13-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.21.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from fra16s13-in-f238.1e100.net (172.217.21.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=15.9 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.775/14.608/15.908/0.936 ms
```

**Next step:** Enable Network Address Translation (NAT) so routed packages can return to devices on the access point. Extend wpa_supplicant with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements. Have attention to the minus sign after equal `=-` on some statements. Save it and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Start wpa_supplicant again:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

**Checkpoint 9:** Now you should be able to get into the internet with the mobile phone.

That's it.

If you run into trouble you can try a new attempt with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable hostapd.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

This is not a working installation. You have to edit `hostapd.service` and `wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` as shown in my other answer.